# Mysterious FireBug Error repeats with ExtJS

Tags: extjs4, firebug, extjs4.1

When debugging ExtJS 4 (tried both versions 4.1.0 and 4.1.1), FireBug repeatedly shows the following error: `An invalid or illegal string was specified
http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/extjs/ext-all.js
Line 18`. It does not break on the error, though that option is specified. Additionally, neither my code or ext-debug.js and it's loader seem to actually call ext-all.js.

This error gets logged to Firebug's console about once per minute, which is annoying. What bothers me is that I cannot get the error to go away. Is this a FireBug bug? An ExtJS bug? Aliens? How can I debug the debugger?

Comment: Can you post some of your code?

Comment: I'd have done that if I could determine which sections to post. I've removed just about everything but the viewport and a few Ext.panel.Panels. That is the problem -- it does not seem to be related to my code at all.

Comment: There could be some missing character in the ExtJS lib (unlikely) or in your code. Do you, by any chance, have the extjs docs open on a tab when you debug the app? Regardless, could you please close all browser windows, open in Firefox one of the examples from the extjs/examples folder and let us know if you still get the error when you debug it?

Comment: **NOTE:** After installing a number of updates, including a FireFox point bump and possibly a FireBug update, I no longer get this error. * I have not changed the ExtJS code I use (reverted via git to check) nor have I changed the ExtJS libs which are served on the same development machine. *

Comment: Fyi, last time when I have my project launched in Firefox, everything works just fine. But just when I started firebug, my code halt and error spawned. Thou I can't remember what error it was, but it is definitely true that Firebug isn't that friendly to ExtJS. Try using Chrome instead.

Comment: The bug has gone mysteriously.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem before and I've solved it by removing a special character at the end of my `JS` file! (`app.js` I think)

It was weird, but the problem came from hidden special characters like: **Zero-width non-joiner** or **Right-to-left mark**.

Open another JS file but **do not** copy/paste your code there. Just write it again and check whether the problem exists or not.

And don't forget to check your **data** if you have some. As this article explains about the problem: http://www.ashorlivs.fr/javascript-jquery/article/an-invalid-or-illegal-string-was

Answer (score 0):

For general debugging see this link http://www.sencha.com/learn/debugging-ext-js-applications/
You can also use ext-all-dev.js while in development mode. 
There is another excellent tool on top of firebug, at this link http://www.illuminations-for-developers.com/

PS: I still didn't figured out how to post a comment. I guess it comes when I have more points/reputation. Hence adding it as an answer. thanks.